# How to run TestCafe on another server

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm following the TestCafe docs and I get how to write a test and run it locally from the command line. What I'm wondering is how I could host the tests on a remote server and execute them from somewhere else. So far the only way I can see to do it is by setting up the remote server with API that then executes a command to run the TestCafe tests. Is there a simpler way to accomplish this where it can just run the tests with out executing a command?

Comment: Based on the description, I assume that you are looking for a way to run your tests in a browser on a remote device. Please refer to the following topic: [Test on Remote Computers and Mobile Devices](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/basics/test-on-remote-computers-and-mobile-devices.html).

Comment: To give more context. We want our tests to be run by non technical people. People that will not be able to use a terminal or console. Instead we plan to let them fill out a form which will call an API built in node.js and Express that will then trigger the tests and return JSON. Right now the only way I can get the API to trigger the tests is using exec function that then executes the commands. While this works, it feels hacky to me and I'm searching for a better way to accomplish this. Thanks for taking a look at this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a TestCafe instance in the NodeJS script and use TestCafe API to run your tests:

```js
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe         = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe     = tc;
        const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

        return runner
            .src('test.js')
            .browsers('chrome')
            .run();
    })
    .then(failedCount => {
        console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
        testcafe.close();
    });
```

Please refer to the following topics to find more info about this approach:
[Runner Object](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/testcafe-api/runner/), [TestCafe Object](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/testcafe-api/testcafe/)

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help with this!